# How to parse JSON Array of String in android

Tags: java, android

this is the response from the server

```
{"route":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

This is my code:

```
try{
String d = json.getString("route");
}
}catch(JSONException je){
}
```

and im getting NullPointerException.
please help me.

This is my Server Response, Now Give me the solution 
Link -> `http://ajax.tpksym.cloudbees.net/route/route14`

Comment: Can you please show us more code snippet.

Comment: the answer is given please have a look, fully pared and tested, add try/catch block with yourself

Comment: [link](http://ajax.tpksym.cloudbees.net/route/route14)
This is the response from my server.

Comment: hi than please choose double in place of int in the answer

Comment: The answer is again updated please have a look

Answer (score 1):

It should be like:

```
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject("{\"route\":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}");
JSONArray array = jsonResult.getJSONArray("route");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
     int data = array.getInt(i);
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi as yours json is as follows

```
{
  "route": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6
  ]
}
```

so do as follows

```
String jsondata = "{\"route\":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}";
        JSONObject primaryObject = new JSONObject(jsondata);

        JSONArray jarray = primaryObject.getJSONArray("route");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            Integer data = jarray.getInt(i);
            System.out.println("data=="+data);
        }
```

as you gave the link http://ajax.tpksym.cloudbees.net/route/route14

and data seems there coming as in double  i.e. 13.56 etc

so use as follows

```
String jsondata = "JSON DATA FROM SERVER";
        JSONObject primaryObject = new JSONObject(jsondata);

        JSONArray jarray = primaryObject.getJSONArray("route");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            Double data = jarray.getDouble(i);

        }
```

Comment: sorry i'm getting NullPointerException :(

Comment: where ? can you send the log? if double is having a problem that treat it as string and later you can conver it to double or else

Comment: i do not think nullpointer exception is in parsing as if the exception will be there than it will be of type JSONException  not nullpointer, please check log, have a debug and than solve

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        String jsonString = "{\"route\":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("route");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
           System.out.println(jsonArray.getInt(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```